# Convert concatenated characters (char) to String literal in Java

Tags: java, string, character, literals

```
public class Tester{
  public static void main (String args[]){

  String word="sandwich";
  char newWord[]=word.toCharArray();

  System.out.println(word.equals(transform(newWord)));
  if (word.equals(transform(newWord))){
      System.out.println("same");}
      else{
        System.out.println("not");
      }

  }
  public static String transform(char [] newWord){
    for(int i=0; i<newWord.length;i++)
    {
      System.out.print(String.valueOf(newWord[i]));
      //System.out.print(""+newWord[i]);

    }
   return "";
  }
    }
```

RESULT>> sandwich false
         sandwich not

Is there a way to convert a concatenated 'string' of characters to a string literal?

Comment: Use `System.out.println(word.equals(newWord));`

Comment: Thank you, but this is an example where it will not work. The altered string is not equivalent to the string literal so .equals() does not recognize them as equal.

Comment: Can you provide an example what you are trying to do? Try [ideone](http://ideone.com/).

Comment: @cpx. Just put up sample code. Thank you.

Comment: You don't need `transform` method. Just use `String s = String.valueOf(newWord);` to convert `char[]` to `String`.

Comment: @cpx. Dang, so close. I thought this would solve my problem, but the transform method is requred to do the grunt of the transformation work. So, the value from the method is what needs to be converted to a string literal.

Comment: If the goal is to convert `char[]` to `String` then what is the issue with `String.valueOf(newWord)`?

Comment: A method is used to convert and reform a string literal using some conditions. So, the original literal is taken apart and put together by some specific means. The result is then passed to be used to compare with the original literal. In my case, whether the reconstituted 'string' result is IDENTICAL to the original string literal. My example code indicates, even with the use of the valueOf(), for example, that they are not equivalent. The resulting mash-up of chars from the method is not recognized as a string literal equivalent. I hope that helps.

Comment: Here's the [correct way](http://pastebin.com/wQm5p744) to transform it into String if you're using a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should never compare Strings with `==` (unless you know exactly what you are doing).

Use `.equals()` instead.

Comment: The newly formed 'string' of characters is NOT equivalent to a string literal, so .equals is false. How can I convert the newly formed characters to a string literal?